# awk delimiter regex

Tags: awk, delimiter

I'm trying to extract all the numbers (just the numbers) from a file that looks like this (always three '|||') AND MAKE SURE the number is being followed by 3 |||

```
file:
12342|||blah blah
31221|||foo bar
12342|||bar foo
```

I want to get only 12342,31221,12342

So far I have

```
//works
echo "2333|||test" | awk -F  "([^1-9])+\|"  '{print $1}'

// should fail and return none
echo "2333|||test" | awk -F  "([^1-9])+\|+"  '{print $1}'
```

Any idea?

Comment: What should happen with input `123||||abc`?  That's 4 pipes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk -F'|' '/^[1-9]+\|/ && NF == 4 {print $1}' data.txt`

Comment: Nice.  Two minor quibbles.  (1) It allows '123|a|b|c' as valid. (2) It does not allow '123|||abc|def' through.  The second is a definitional issue; it may or may not be correct to reject that.  The first is more serious; it would be fixed by checking that `$2 == "" && $3 == ""`.

Answer (score 3):

you mean like this??

```
awk -F'\\|\\|\\|' '{print $1}'
```

catch the text before exact three "|||"

```
grep -Po "^\d+(?=\|\|\|)"

kent$  grep -Po "^\d+(?=\|\|\|)" <<<"2333||tes"

kent$  grep -Po "^\d+(?=\|\|\|)" <<<"2333|||tes"
2333
```

Comment: ,did you even test it ?  
echo "2333||test" | awk -F'\\|\\|\\|'  '{print $1}'

Comment: @user914584 see the added grep line

Answer (score 1):

If you might have lines with a number followed by two pipes and you don't want those, then...if you have GNU `grep`, you can use:

```
grep -o '^[0-9][0-9]*|||' file | awk -F '|' '{print $1}'
```

You could use `sed` instead of `awk` for the post-processing.  The `-o` option is specific to GNU `grep` and not reliably portable, therefore.

If you must reject lines with 4 pipes after the number, you have to work harder:

```
grep -E -o '^[0-9]+\|{3}($|[^|])' file | awk -F '|' '{print $1}'
```

The extended (`egrep`) regex looks for start of line, one or more digits, three pipe symbols, followed either by end-of-line or another non-pipe character.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extended grep alternative:

```
grep -oE '^[0-9]+\|{3}($|[^|])' file | grep -oE '[0-9]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
awk -F\| '{if (NF >= 4) print $1}' <foo
12342
31221
12342
```

Comment: Nahh need the numbers not the blah blah foo ar parts. As well as making sure it only select numbers when its in the beginning and being followed by 3 |||

Comment: How to make sure the numbers are followed by three(3) ||| ?

Comment: This allow spaces between '|' if that's a problem.